# Increase Diff limits in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

We have on premise Gitlab installation and want to display big diffs. According to comments from this issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/30061 we made following changes

```
vim /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/models/commit.rb
DIFF_HARD_LIMIT_FILES = 10000
DIFF_HARD_LIMIT_LINES = 500000
vim /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/git/diff.rb
DIFF_SIZE_LIMIT = 1024000 # 1000 KB
DIFF_COLLAPSE_LIMIT = 102400 # 100 KB
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
gitlab-ctl restart unicorn
```

and have no luck. Is there a proper way to increase diff limits in gitlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like its editable from the GUI now.

```
    CAUTION: Caution:
This setting is experimental. An increased maximum will increase resource
consumption of your instance. Keep this in mind when adjusting the maximum.

Go to Admin Area > Settings > General.
Expand Diff limits.
Enter a value for Maximum diff patch size, measured in bytes.
Click on Save changes.
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/admin_area/diff_limits.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an open issue on this:  https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17609